# Acumatica OData as JSON (instead of Atom)

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know if it's possible to get an Acumatica OData endpoint to return JSON instead of Atom?

By default, it looks to me like the format is Atom:
[image: Acumatica OData as JSON (instead of Atom)]

But this seems to indicate that JSON might be a possible alternative:
https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options available:

1. Use [Format System Query Option](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#theformatsystemqueryoption) (just add `$format=json` to the query string)
2. If you're doing an integration, you can also request the JSON format using `Accept` HTTP Header (see [this article](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/json-verbose-format/#requestingverbosejsonformat) for more details).

Comment: Thank you both. This is exactly what I was looking for. I documented it further, including how to connect to the JSON format using Excel here: https://www.timrodman.com/augforums/acumatica-odata-with-microsoft-excel-and-power-bi/using-json-with-odata-in-acumatica/

Comment: External OData clients pass `Accept` header to retrieve data in the proper format. Excel, for example, requests `application/json`, so there is no point to pass it in the query string when using Excel as a client.